# urllib.requiest.urlopen error: certificate verify failed on python Virtual Environment

Tags: python, ssl-certificate, urllib, urlopen

Im building a Web Scapper, when testing on venv -> [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
But, when I'm testing on ipython shell -> Perfectly good

I wondering what the root problem is?
Thanks for your help!`from urllib.request import urlopen

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import subprocess

html = urlopen('http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page3.html')
bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
html_tags = bs.prettify()`

Comment: can you share some of your code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: hmm, just url -> then get the html_context with urlopen, and then the SSL certificate Error. Im not understand good about how the SSL certificate work? Any advice? 
Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing `pip install certifi` with your **venv** and add another valid certificate from any website with https:

[10 ways to get valid ssl](https://blog.hubspot.com/website/best-free-ssl-certificate-sources)

Also this is how you add a certificate to `certifi` library:

[adding certs to requests](https://incognitjoe.github.io/adding-certs-to-requests.html)

Comment: thanks for you response! 
I also tried with the conda -env : its work really well, maybe conda env has installed the certificate package as default.
But I've tried with the `pip install certifi`, but it still not work. Maybe I'm not understand good enough about how the PKI works. Any recommend about this topic, I appreciate that! Have a good day!

Comment: yes, pythons `certifi` comes with its own certificates, they are located in a file called `certifi/cacert.pem`, if it still doesn't work you have to add a new certificate. Virtually any theory or literature will help you, just google PKI or SSL with python.

Comment: yw, please accept my answer if it helped solve your problem, ty! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just understand why it could leads into this problems!
If your guys using an virtual env (such as: create a by using `python3 -m venv .venv` -> it will absolutely isolate (easy to understand right?)
But once it isolate from the current machine -> the ip address still not change!
However the dependencies with others are cut down already -> This could lead to the about situation!
but when your guys create a `venv` (by conda) -> it setting more detailed -> so it might by not crash into the problem.
If somethings wrong, im happy to get the replies for this one!
PS: Python Automation Cookbook - packs helped me to understand this problem deeply! and ChatGPT: network dependencies and lib in venv.

Comment: Just to clear things up about why your IP doesn't change. A virtual environment in Python is just isolated to all other *python environments* on your computer. In other words: a Python virtual environment is just a clean slate to work from. Everything is still running on your machine and is not isolated to your hardware even a little bit.